# Can't upload a file using Parse.File for a express web app

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform

I'm creating an express web app and Parse backend. I'm using .ejs file to render webpages. When the submit button is clicked in the file upload form, express routes me to testfile.js where i use Parse.File method to upload file to Parse db. I think i got a problem with my function which extracts the file from the submitted form. I'm attaching testfile.js and .ejs file which contain upload form. please check and suggest me right answer.This is my testfile.js.

```
exports.xmlfile = function(req, res) {
var filecontrol = $("#myfile")[0];
var file= filecontrol.files[0];

var parseFile= new Parse.File("8706388_orig.jpg",file);
parseFile.save().then(function(){
var newobj= new Parse.Object;
newobj.set('file', parseFile);
newobj.save();
res.redirect('/administrator');
});
};
```

And this is .ejs file upload form

```
<form class="form form2" id="myform" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data"    method="post" action="/administrator">
      <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
      <input class="w-button upload" type="submit" value="Upload" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To make sure that you get relevant answers, would you please describe your exact problem in more detail and post the actual error reports if appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saving the file correctly, but the object you're trying to attach it to isn't declared properly.

The most common pattern (as per the docs) is to declare your class, then create an instance of it, for example if your class is named "Foo":

```
var Foo = Parse.Object.extend("Foo");
var foo = new Foo();
foo.set("file", parseFile);
```

Lastly, you should wait for the save to finish before redirecting:

```
foo.save().then(function() {
    res.redirect("/administrator");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Timothy, and i'm sorry for a late response.